# System.IO.File.Move gives Exception "The file exists"

Tags: .net, exception

Normally if you try move to a file that exists, File.Move throws a message "Cannot create a file when that file already exists".

I am getting a situation where File.Move throws

> "The file exists"

This exception is thrown by `System.IO.__Error.WinIOError` directly after doing `File.Move`

It is attempting to move a file to a network drive.

After some searching, the only other thing which gives this particular message, seems to be `Path.GetTempFileName()` - which can throw this if the temp folder is full.

I'm not using `GetTempFileName`, and the temp folder is not full.

Does anyone know what may cause this, or how to troubleshoot?
(this is on a managed server, for which only the managing company has access, and I can not show the proprietary code here).

Comment: It's rather difficult to say what the problem is if you don't give us the entire exception and stack trace.

Comment: I'll try clarify my question. Its not a "spot the code bug" question, but rather, under what circumstances does File.Move normally throw "The file exists"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comes out of Windows, different error codes for different scenarios.  The second one is ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS, "Cannot create a file when that file already exists" when the file is moved from one directory to another *on the same drive*.  That's a pretty simple operation, it only requires moving the directory entry.

The first one is ERROR_FILE_EXISTS, "The file exists" when the file is moved from one drive *to another drive*.  That's a much more involved operation, the file data has to be copied as well.  In other words, it falls back to the equivalent of File.Copy(string, string, bool) with the last *overwrite* argument set to false.  That it doesn't use the same error code is a bit of a quirk.  The difference is a big deal to the file system driver, just not to your program.  Otherwise the reason that you just get a pretty generic IOException instead of a more specific one that breaks down the file manipulation mishaps into finer-grained exceptions.

It isn't actually a problem because there isn't anything you can do about it in your code, you need the help of a human to correct the problem.  Unless you take specific pre-emptive measures in your own code, either avoiding the move if the destination file already exists or by actually deleting the destination file first.  Do note that neither is a 100% reliable workaround, there's a very small chance that another process creates the file again right after you deleted it but before you move.  Making file operations completely reliable is pretty difficult on a multi-tasking operating system.

Comment: Thanks Hans, your answer sounds close. This is a move to a network drive (edited question). I searched for documentation to that effect, but found none. Do you have a reference?

Comment: A reference for what?  I just created one afaik.

Comment: I've just confirmed this by creating a console app attempting to move a file to network drive, where the file already exists.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have to specify the file name, assuming of course that you aren't. It helps to show your code, but I'll make the assumption you're doing:

```
File.Move(@"C:\Folder\File.txt", @"C:\Folder2")
```

Instead, try:

```
File.Move(@"C:\Folder\File.txt", @"C:\Folder2\File.txt")
```

Comment: You need to escape your slashes or use the verbatim strings. That is, either `"C:\\Folder\\File.txt"` or `@"C:\Folder\File.txt"`.

Comment: Also, giving only the directory name throws the same exception as specifying a file name that exists.

Comment: Right, was kinda absent mindedly putting that. But I don't know about that for sure, because he said he's getting two different errors, one when he puts it where the file exists, but I don't know how he's doing that. Frankly this is largely a guess since I have no idea what his code is or where the error could lie

Answer (score 2):

Using .NET Core 3.0 or above, the Move method has a new Boolian parameter to set the overwrite to true, which will replace the file if it exists.

```
Move(String, String, Boolean)
```

You can find more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move?view=netcore-3.0) about that.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to accomplish this:

```
public void Move(string uncPath)
        {
            var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Constants.ROOT_PATH, "*.csv");

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                var item = file.GetAfter("\\");
                File.Copy(file, uncPath + item);
                File.Delete(file);
            }
        }
```

I've tested this and it's working like a charm. Hope it helps somebody